# How to delete some text from HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, string

I have an HTML like this into a PHP variable called `$html`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyPage</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>MyPage</h1>
        <h2>{SUBTITLE}</h2>
        <div>{BODY}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to delete the tag and the contents inside the tag,  if inside the tag only appears `{something}`. For example, in this case, the lines:

```
<h2>{SUBTITLE}</h2>
<div>{BODY}</div>
```

Must be deleted.

I was thinking in something like that:

```
$html = str_replace('{'%%'}', '', $html);
```

This line doesn't work, but what I try to do it's, replace words that starts and ends by '{' and '}' with nothing (I don't know how to do it), and the other problem is how to delete the empty tags as well.

Comment: Use `preg_replace()` instead of `str_replace()` with regexp. http://php.net/preg_replace

Comment: The best one I think is to use XPath with regex - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38916869/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression.

Your regular expression could look like this:

`<\w*>{\w*}<\/\w*>`

This searches for a starting `<`, followed by 1-n literals or numbers, followed by `>`. Then followed by `{`, 1-n literals or numbers,`}`, `</`, 1-n literals or numbers and finally the closing `>`

```
$html = preg_replace('/<\w*>{\w*}<\/\w*>/', '', $html);
```

This would not only replace the content, but remove the tags themselves as well.

Comment: Short, effective and easy to understand. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using regex inside XPath approach here: get all element nodes that have text starting with `{` and ending with `}` with `/^{[^}]+}$/` (the regex can be adjusted to say `/^{[A-Z]+}$/`):

```
$xpath->query("//*[php:functionString('preg_match', '$regex', text())>0]")
```

This line just gets all elements (`*`) whose inner text (`text()`) matches the `$regex`.

And here is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/ohuSby):

```
$html = "<YOU_HTML_STRING_HERE>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html,  LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // Load the HTML  string and init DOM

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); // Init XPATH
// you need to register the namespace "php" to make it available in the query
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPhpFunctions();

// add delimiter to your pattern
$regex = '/^{[^}]+}$/';

// search your node anywhere in the DOM tree with "//"
$items = $xpath->query("//*[php:functionString('preg_match', '$regex', text())>0]");

foreach ($items as $tag) {
    $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's too many code versus only one line of code : )

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to match all code fragments between html tags, wrapped in `{}`. In your case that would become:

```
$html = '<html><head><title>MyPage</title><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><body><h1>MyPage</h1><h2>{SUBTITLE}</h2><div>{BODY}</div></body></html>';
$pattern = '/<([\w]+)[^>]*>{([^}]*)}<\/\1>/';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $html);
// outputs <html><head><title>MyPage</title><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><body><h1>MyPage</h1></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex is fraught with problems, I'd go with `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`

```
$html='
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyPage</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>MyPage</h1>
        <h2>{SUBTITLE}</h2>
        <h2>Gigantic Ants ate my brain</h2>
        <div>{BODY}</div>
        <div>Squashed by a green banana</div>
    </body>
</html>';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );

/* tweak the XPath queries to suit your requirements */
/*
   There are many XPath cheatsheets available but for reference:
   http://xpath.alephzarro.com/content/cheatsheet.html
   http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf
*/
$col=$xp->query('//h2[contains(text(),"{SUBTITLE}")]|//div[contains(text(),"{BODY}")]');

if( $col ){
    foreach( $col as $n )$n->parentNode->removeChild( $n );
}

echo '<textarea cols=100 rows=50>',$dom->saveHTML(),'</textarea>';
$dom=$xp=null;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question since the contents between `{...}` can be any.

Comment: the question was a little vague on the contents but some simple tweaking of the query could yield the desired results

Comment: See [my approach using a regex inside XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38916869/3832970), I think it is the most flexible here.

Comment: I saw it - I like it

Comment: In fact, I like it a lot so +1